# Get reference to Object whose List an Object is contained in

Tags: c#, list, reference

Considering the following case in C#:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo() { }        
}

class Foo2
{
    private List<Foo> m_List = new List<Foo>();    
    public Foo2() { m_List.Add(new Foo); }    
}

Foo2 fooInstance = new Foo2();
```

Foo2 owns a List that contains a Foo - is there any built-in way for the Foo to figure out which List it's contained in, and which object that list belongs to? In other words, can Foo obtain a reference to Foo2, or do I have to add an explicit backwards reference in Foo - pointing to Foo2 - as I've been doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foo` will have no knowledge that it is contained within a list unless you specify that somehow. A list after all is just a set of references to a location in memory. There is no relationship from a pointer to what contains the pointer.

```
class Foo
{
     public Foo2 Parent { get; protected set; }

     public Foo(Foo2 parent)
     {
         Parent = parent;
     }
}

class Foo2
{
      public Foo2()
      {
          List<Foo> x = new List<Foo>
          {
              new Foo(this)
          };
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no built-in way. Instances of Foo only know about themselves, the public interface of their members, and the public/protected interface of their base class, if they have one.

If you give a little more context about what you're trying to do, I may be able to offer you an alternative solution.

Comment: Imagine a simple graph where an object owns a list of objects, each of which owns a list of objects, etc. pp... I was just looking for a super easy way to traverse the graph backwards. I'm already doing fine accomplishing this in the traditional ways.

Comment: This is the reason why you see .parent on Controls for example, so you can recurse up the tree of owners.

Answer (score 0):

No; that's inherently impossible.

What if you put the same object in two lists?

Comment: Then I'd expect a List of objects that I can iterate over, instead of a single reference. But I'll immediately accept that this isn't possible, it's one of those "wouldn't it be nice if, and you never know" things I've been confronted with.